# TTNavigator won't load external URL when called from MoreViewController

Tags: xcode, ios, three20

There seems to be a bug in the implementation of Three20 TTNavigator.

When I try to load an external URL in any of the first four controllers in the tabbar it works.

However when I try calling it in any additional viewcontrollers in the tabbar (those being pushed to MoreViewController), nothing runs when i clicked on the link. Except this being shown in console. 
[Switching to process xxxx thread 0x0]

Any idea?

Thanks, Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Found it

http://three20.pypt.lt/url-based-navigation-tab-bar-and-more...-tab-bug